# Not able to access shinyDriver in R

Tags: r, shiny

i am getting error message when I run the below code. i loaded both shinytest and shinyloadtest

```
app <- ShinyDriver$new("d:/Newfolder/Folder1")
Error in session_makeRequest(self, private, endpoint, data, params, headers) : 
  Can't find variable: $
```

Comment: What is the contents of `"d:/Newfolder/Folder1"` ?

Comment: It’s a project directory. It has ui.R , server.R and many more files

Comment: Are you sure this app is working ? Such an error could happen when there's a missing package for example. Otherwise, try to upgrade the `shinytest` package and its dependencies.

Comment: You were right. One package was uninstalled without my notice 

Comment: Hi . I got it solved. But can you tell me one thing. This particular package actually checks difference between current and expected results. But what is the use of this when we have github that shows the changes happened?